# CreateInputLayout returns E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-11

I am writing a program in C++ using DirectX11. Now I wanted to start with shaders and for that I also need the ID3D11InputLayout

```
//in main
shader.Bind(DeviceContext);

ID3D11InputLayout *pLayout;
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
};

HRESULT hh = Device->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, shader.GetVSBlob()->GetBufferPointer(), shader.GetVSBlob()->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);

DeviceContext->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);

//Vertex Shader
struct VOut
{
float4 position : SV_POSITION;
float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut main(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
VOut output;

output.position = position;
output.color = color;

return output;
}
//pixel shader
struct VOut
{
float4 position : SV_POSITION;
float4 color : COLOR;
};

float4 main(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
return color;
}
```

Device->CreateInputLayout() returns E_INVALIDARG.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the [Direct3D Debug Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers) and look for debug output.

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout: The provided input signature expects
to read an element with SemanticName/Index: 'SV_Position'/0, but the declaration
doesn't provide a matching name.
[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #163: CREATEINPUTLAYOUT_MISSINGELEMENT]
```

In this case you'd see that you used the legacy "POSITION" semantic in the layout, but "SV_Position" in the shader. They need to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In your description you have POSITION defined as R32G32B32, but the shader is expected a float4, is that why?

Either that, or there is something wrong with blob data. I assume shaders blob data is for a Vertex shader and not a pixel shader?

Comment: Shaders blob data is for both

Comment: Try that:

`float4 main(VOut input) : SV_TARGET
{
 return input.color;
}`